# How to convert hex to char string in perl

Tags: perl, char, hex

I need change the %xx HEX characters to chars. I am trying with this code but it does not works:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

my $cadena = "%40%61%62";
print $cadena."\n";
$cadena =~ s/%//g;
print "cad: ".$cadena."\n";
my $string =~ s/([a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9])/chr(hex($1))/eg;
print "traducida: ".$string;
```

Comment: Always put `use warnings` and `use strict` top of the program.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your advice. I am learning perl, all advices are good.

Comment: Tip: You could use `s/([[:xdigit:]]{2})/chr(hex($1))/eg` instead to avoid long classes and redundant code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change

```
my $string =~ s/([a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9])/chr(hex($1))/eg;
```

to

```
$cadena =~ s/([a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9])/chr(hex($1))/eg;
```

so that search and replace is done on `$cadena`.

Output: `@ab`

```
40 => @
61 => a
62 => b
```

Comment: @Asier: We all have that problem. That's why we have `use strict` and `use warnings`.

Answer (score 2):

A better regex pattern:

```
$cadena =~ s/([[:xdigit:]]{2})/chr(hex($1))/eg;
```

Use the POSIX character set `[:xdigit:]` to match a single hexadecimal character and use `{2}` to specify two and only two of them.

Comment: This non-answer could easily have been posted as a comment.

Comment: Not at all: *Tip: You could use `s/([[:xdigit:]]{2})/chr(hex($1))/eg` instead to avoid long classes and redundant code.*

Comment: Changing `$cadena` to `my $string` on the LHS of `s///` is the opposite of fixing a bug!