# How to convert char string to hex in perl

Tags: perl

I read this post:
[How to convert hex to char string in perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40738323/how-to-convert-hex-to-char-string-in-perl)
to convert hex to chart string.

How can I do reverse operation? I need convert char string to hex in perl. For example, I have string "**hello world!**" and I must get:

```
00680065006C006C006F00200077006F0072006C00640021
```

Comment: How do you want to handle characters larger than 0xFFFF?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's another approach. Do it all in one go with a regex.

```
my $string = 'hello world!';
$string =~ s/(.)/sprintf '%04x', ord $1/seg;
```

Comment: @FlorianB, 1) `.` already matches newline because of `/s` 2) Why would you want to needlessly limit yourself to the first 256 Unicode chars?!

Answer (score 7):

One algorithm you can use to do this is:

- break the string into characters
- convert the character to [its numerical value](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/ord.html) (also see [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) and [perlunicode](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlunicode.html))
- [convert](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html) the base-10 number to hexadecimal with four digits
- stick it back together and/or output

A possible implementation could be

```
print map { sprintf '%04X', ord } split //, 'hello world!';
```

The output of this program is

```
00680065006C006C006F00200077006F0072006C00640021
```

That said, there is probably a [`pack`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html) implementation that I am not aware of.

Comment: I got the expected output with `uc join "", unpack '(H2)*', pack '(xa)*', split //, $input`. I don't know how to shorten it :-)

Comment: @choroba, Replace `'(xa)*'` with `'n*` to handle chars up to 0xFFFF instead of chars up to 0xFF. With that fix, simplifying `join "", unpack '(H2)*',` to `unpack 'H*',`, and replacing `split` with `unpack` for style, we get: `uc unpack 'H*', pack 'n*', unpack 'W*', $input`.

Answer (score 7):

The exiting answers provide the hex representation of the Unicode Code Points.

That format doesn't permit the input to include any characters above 0xFFFF. If it were to permit this, there would be no way to know if

```
20000200002000020000
```

means

```
2000 0200 0020 0002 0000
```

or

```
20000 20000 20000 20000
```

If that's fine because you'll never have characters above 0xFFFF, then I recommend the following:

```
my $text = 'hello world!';
my $hex = uc unpack 'H*', pack 'n*', unpack 'W*', $text;
```

It should be much faster than the existing solutions, and it handles characters above 0xFFFF better than the existing solutions (since it still provides only 4 hex digits for characters above 0xFFFF).

---

If, however, you want to handle all Unicode Code Points, the above solution and the solution provided by the earlier answers aren't adequate.

With that in mind, I suspect you actually want the hex representation of the UTF-16be encoding of the Unicode Code Points. At worse, having a character above 0xFFFF will still produce useful and lossless output.

```
Code Point    Perl string lit  JSON string lit  Hex of UCP  Hex of UTF-16be
------------  ---------------  ---------------  ----------  ---------------
h  (U+0068)   "\x{68}          "\u0068"         0068        0068
é  (U+00E9)   "\x{E9}          "\u00E9"         00E9        00E9
ጀ  (U+1300)   "\x{1300}        "\u1300"         1300        1300
 (U+20000)  "\x{20000}       "\uD840\uDC00"   20000       D840DC00
```

If that's the case, you want

```
use Encode qw( encode );

my $text = 'hello world!';
my $hex = uc unpack 'H*', encode 'UTF-16be', $text;
```