# How can I escape a string in Perl for LDAP searching?

Tags: perl, ldap

I want to escape a string, per RFC 4515. So, the string "u1" would be transformed to "\75\31", that is, the ordinal value of each character, in hex, preceded by backslash.

Has to be done in Perl. I already know how to do it in Python, C++, Java, etc., but Perl if baffling.

Also, I cannot use Net::LDAP and I may not be able to add any new modules, so, I want to do it with basic Perl features.

Comment: You may not one able to use Net::LDAP, but you can look at its source to see what it does.

Answer (score 2):

In short, one way is just as the question says: split the string into characters, get their ordinals then convert format to hex; then put it back together. I don't know how to get the `\nn` format so I'd make it 'by hand'. For instance

```
my $s = join '', map { sprintf '\%x', ord }  split //, 'u1';
```

Or use [vector flag `%v`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf#vector-flag) to treat the string as a "vector" of integers

```
my $s = sprintf '\%*vx', '\\', 'u1';
```

With `%v` the string is broken up into numerical representation of characters, each is converted (`%x`), and they're joined back, with `.` between them.  That (optional) `*` allows us to specify our string by which to join them instead, `\` (escaped) here.

This can also be done with [pack](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack) + [unpack](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unpack), see the link below.  Also see that page if there is a wide range of input characters.<sup>†</sup>

See [ord](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/ord) and [sprintf](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf), and for more pages like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56183870/how-to-convert-char-string-to-hex-in-perl).

---

<sup>†</sup>  If there is non-ASCII input then you may need to encode it so to get octets, if they are to escape (and not whole codepoints)

```
use Encode qw(encode);

my $s = sprintf '\%*vx', '\\', encode('UTF_8', $input);
```

See the linked page for more.

Comment: `my $s = join '', map { sprintf "\\%02x", ord } split //, 'u1'`?

Comment: @Shawn But of course -- thank you!  I got stuck with something else I was trying initially...  Btw, seems hard to beat the `%v`, it's tailored for this (unless there is something else about it that's suboptimal or off).  The other option is interesting as well

Comment: The vector one will have issues with non-ASCII text. According to the RFC, it's the individual bytes of UTF-8 encoded text that are supposed to be escaped, but it'll use codepoints for unicode strings. Need to convert it first if that's the case.

Comment: @Shawn Yeah, was just looking into it ... works with your `Lučić` though.  Not sure about codepoints, while the `%v` part on the `sprintf` page mentions "characters" that whole page has not words unicode nor utf.

Comment: It produces `\4c\75\10d\69\107` (Note the three-digit  values), not the `\4c\75\c4\8d\69\c4\87` it should (Unless you're not including a `use utf8;` in the test.) The string `"Lu\N{U+010D}i\N{U+0107}"` would be better for testing, come to think.

Comment: @Shawn Good point, I didn't have `use utf8;` so it didn't encode it... But then the other approaches don't work with it either

Answer (score 2):

Skimming through RFC 4515, this encoding escapes the individual octets of multi-byte UTF-8 characters, not codepoints. So, something that works with non-ASCII text too:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw/say/;

sub valueencode ($) {
    # Unpack format returns octets of UTF-8 encoded text
    my @bytes = unpack "U0C*", $_[0];
    sprintf '\%02x' x @bytes, @bytes;
}

say valueencode 'u1';
say valueencode "Lu\N{U+010D}i\N{U+0107}"; # Lučić, from the RFC 4515 examples
```

Example:

```sh
$ perl demo.pl
\75\31
\4c\75\c4\8d\69\c4\87
```

Or an alternative using the vector flag:

```perl
use Encode qw/encode/;

sub valueencode ($) {
    sprintf '\%*vx', "\\", encode('UTF-8', $_[0]);
}
```

---

Finally, a smarter version that only escapes ASCII characters when it has to (And multi-byte characters, even though upon a closer read of the RFC they don't actually *need* to be if they're valid UTF-8):

```perl
# Encode according to RFC 4515 valueencoding grammar rules:
#
# Text is UTF-8 encoded. Bytes can be escaped with the sequence
# \XX, where the X's are hex digits.
#
# The characters NUL, LPAREN, RPAREN, ASTERISK and BACKSLASH all MUST
# be escaped.
#
# Bytes > 0x7F that aren't part of a valid UTF-8 sequence MUST be
# escaped. This version assumes there are no such bytes and that input
# is a ASCII or Unicode string.
#
# Single bytes and valid multibyte UTF-8 sequences CAN be escaped,
# with each byte escaped separately. This version escapes multibyte
# sequences, to give ASCII results.
sub valueencode ($) {
    my $encoded = "";
    for my $byte (unpack 'U0C*', $_[0]) {
        if (($byte >= 0x01 && $byte <= 0x27) ||
            ($byte >= 0x2B && $byte <= 0x5B) ||
            ($byte >= 0x5D && $byte <= 0x7F)) {
            $encoded .= chr $byte;
        } else {
            $encoded .= sprintf '\%02x', $byte;
        }
    }
    return $encoded;
}
```

This version returns the strings `'u1'` and `'Lu\c4\8di\c4\87'` from the above examples.